# count checkbox class only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

i've written this script to check when checkboxes with classes "A", "B" and "C" are selected and then add them together (these classes are assigned to multiple checkboxes). however, i want to only count one instance of them being checked, whereas this script counts them everytime checkboxes with these values are checked. how can i alter it to only count them once only?

jquery:

```
 $(function() {
        $('#product-counter .counter').text('0');

        var total = $("#search-id-checkboxes .A:checked").length + $("#search-id-checkboxes .B:checked").length + $("#search-id-checkboxes .C:checked").length;
        if(total>0){$("#product-counter .counter").text(total);}
        else{$("#product-counter .counter").text('0');}
    })

    function updateCounter() {
        var len = $("#search-id-checkboxes .A:checked").length + $("#search-id-checkboxes .B:checked").length + $("#search-id-checkboxes .C:checked").length;
        if(len>0){$("#product-counter .counter").text(len);}
        else{$("#product-counter .counter").text('0');}
    }

    $("#search-id-checkboxes input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
        updateCounter();
    });
```

html:

```
<div id="search-id-checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" class="A"/> A<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="A" /> A<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="B" /> B<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" class="B" /> B<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" class="C" /> C<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" class="C" /> C<br />   
</div>
```

Comment: `total` can be reduced to: `$('#search-id-checkboxes').find('.A,.B,.C').filter(':checked').length;`. Same with `len`.

Comment: thanks, but still hasn't solved the problem. the problem is, that when i click either or both of "A" it should only display "1", as opposed to "2"

Answer (score 0):

you already tried the unique method of jquery?
See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

Answer (score 0):

Improvised logic to not have an iterate and work on the total that was calculated inside ready,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MQhyt/

**Full function:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#product-counter .counter').text('0');

    var inArray = [];
    $("#search-id-checkboxes :checkbox").each(function () {
        if (this.checked && $.inArray(this.className, inArray) == -1) {
            inArray.push(this.className);
        }
    });

    var total = inArray.length;

    if (total > 0) {
        $("#product-counter .counter").text(total);
    } else {
        $("#product-counter .counter").text('0');
    }
    $("#search-id-checkboxes input:checkbox").on("change", function () {
        updateCounter.call(this);
    });

    function updateCounter() {
        var elClass = this.className;
        var $el = $('#search-id-checkboxes .' + elClass + ':checked');

        if ($el.length == 1 && this.checked) {
            total += 1;
        } else if ($el.length == 0) {
            total -= 1;
        }

        $("#product-counter .counter").text(total);
    }
});
```

Check out this version http://jsfiddle.net/WLmtq/ using `.each` if you have any issues with above logic.

---

May be you want to check like below,

```
var len = ($("#search-id-checkboxes .A").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0) + 
          ($("#search-id-checkboxes .B").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0) + 
          ($("#search-id-checkboxes .C").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MCKtA/

Comment: thanks so much!!! but one question, is there a way to reduce is since i have 29 different classes and this number will keep expanding....

Answer (score -1):

Use this...

```
var total = 0;
$(':checkbox').on('change', function (e) {
    var a = $(this).prop('class');
    if($("." + a + ':checked').length == 1 && $(this).is(':checked')){
        total +=1;
    }
    if($("." + a + ':checked').length == 0){
        total-=1;
    }
    $('#product-counter .counter').text(total);
});
```

See this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/npfRV/1/)**

Comment: thanks but can the code be shortened to cater for 29 classes which is ever expanding